# The current MacBook Pros -- do the batteries really last longer?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

On their website, Apple [makes a huge deal](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/battery/) about their new battery technology that they're using in the MacBook Pro. In actual practice, is the battery performance really better than the previous generation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anandtech did an article on the battery performance, you might want to read up the [article](http://anandtech.com/mac/showdoc.aspx?i=3580&p=4).

EDIT: [Follow-up article](http://www.anandtech.com/mac/showdoc.aspx?i=3582) to the above, this time with Vista & Windows 7 being used as the OS.

Comment: Interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, it does last longer. But you'll only have a definite answer to the number of times it's rechargeable in about 5 years from the production date. There's several reviewers that confirm the 7h life time, among them MacWorld, Anandtech and TomsHardware.